# Issue showing that the phase of a harmonic wave is invariant under a Galilean transform

Tags: waves, symmetry, galilean-relativity, invariants

The phase $Φ$ of wave is defined as $kx-wt$. It should be the case that all observers moving relative to each other in the non relativistic case will agree on this.

So given the transforms $x'=x-vt$ and $t=t'$,

$Φ'=kx'-wt'$

$=k(x-vt)-wt$

$=kx-wt-kvt$

Seeing as this is wrong, how does one properly show that the phase of a wave is Galilean invariant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordinary wave equation is *not* galilean invariant. It is invariant only under Lorentz transformations with "$c$" being the wave velocity.  This is not unreasonable as the usual wave equation refers to motion in a medium, and if you are moving with respect to the medium  things will seem different. Your algebra shows that in the moving frame 
$$
kx-\omega t \mapsto kx+\omega' t
$$
where $\omega'= \omega+kv$
is the Doppler-shifted frequency.

Comment: Does this also imply that everyone agrees on the wavelength of the harmonic wave, while they may disagree on its speed and frequency? That seems interesting.

Comment: @Vishal. Yes. But then it is obvious that if you ride past a wave, then you will pass the wavecrests at a different rate than if you were stationary...